# iOS - [Fabric firebaseMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics, google-fabric

I tried to integrate Crashlytics 3.9.0 as per manual instruction provided here [Manual Steps](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/update?type=manual). I see integration is succesfull and able to force crash the app but, when the app is launched next time I see the following crash in the fabric. Stack trace below:

`[Crashlytics] Version 3.9.0 (125)
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Packaged report with id <ID> for submission
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting report
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting async /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/file..multipartmime
-[Fabric firebaseMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d009a4a0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Fabric firebaseMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d009a4a0'`

I have enabled the `[Crashlytics sharedInstance].debugMode = YES;` I didn't see much debug information.

I checked the changelog for 3.9.0 release which says SDK updates to support future Firebase integrations.

Is anyone facing this issue ? Any help would be apprciable, thanks in advance.

Comment: look at the code where you are calling the selector "firebaseMode" (method / function ) and check the instance that you are using to call the selector. Th e instance used may be different from what you believe.

Comment: I'm not using firebase, configuring my app to use crashlytics and my code is just initializing fabric `[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];` in app delegate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. We had a bug in our most recent deploy of the SDK when using the Manual Steps mentioned in the post. If you re-download the SDK from the same page and use that, you'll be all set.

Comment: I've integrated Fabric using the Fabric app, not manually, and this just started happening for me. Interestingly, it was NOT happening late last night, but started this morning and I did not change anything related to Fabric at all.  I am invoking it via ` Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])`.

Comment: Interestingly, I had fired up the Fabric app and it said Crashlytics 3.9.3 and I thought I was on that, but after doing some builds, I noticed a ! on Fabric and discovered I was still on 3.9.0. After upgrading to 3.9.3 it's working fine again.